# REORG command does not work in IBM Data studio but same works in Command Line Processor

Tags: db2, db2-luw, ibm-data-studio

I'm using the latest version of IBM Data Studio 4.1.2.0

I tried to reorg a table using IBM Data Studio after some alterations on the table with this command.

```
reorg table MYTABLE;
```

This command shows an error

> REFRESH was expected instead of reorg

But even after using the `REFRESH` command, the table doesn't come out of the "reorg pending" state.

The same command when I tried it via the DB2 Command Line Processor worked perfectly fine.

Any suggestions on how to to enable the `REORG` command in Data Studio or is it not supported at all?

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54245/db2-cannot-use-runstats-reorg-in-trigger-definitions/54246#54246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you tried to run it in an editor window.
YOu have to switch to

> DB2 server Command Line Processor

in the Configuration tab of the editor.
Do not forget to explicitly connect to your database

```
connect to sample ;
reorg table suppliers;
```

Alternatively you could switch to "Administer Databases" and run the reorg from the contect menu of a table:

[image]

Comment: Alternatively (from editor window): `call sysproc.admin_cmd('reorg table suppliers')`

Answer (score 1):

```
 CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( 'REORG TABLE SCHEMA.TABLENAME' )
```

Comment: Jhonnatan, we prefer code snippets highlighted with appropriate tags, please don't roll back the edit.